# Use check_mk_agents on clients to check availability of a service or host

Tags: ping, check-mk, server-monitoring

I hope it's ok to ask rather a settings question instead of a coding-question here.

We are using CheckMK now to monitor some of our services/ servers. We want to use a bunch of clients (in this case raspberry pis, about 150 of them in total) to check if a service is available to them.

The Check-MK server monitors 3 of our servers and several raspberries with the standard deb-package installed on them. Now we see if a server is available and if an rpi is available.
We would like to monitor, if the monitored servers are available from the rpi too. Not just from the Check-MK server.
Reason: The Network is quite big and it is possible that the monitoring-server and the servers which are monitored can communicate, but some rpis are not able to connect to services on those servers.
We want to track down the connection-issues. They seem to be firewall/ hardware related.
So basically I try to use a agent/ client to ping something and report this to check_mk.
Is this possible? I had no luck finding a rule or a setting for this which would be suitable.

Maybe we need a custom API-CALL/ Skript for this?

Thanks in advance
Exa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [local check](https://docs.checkmk.com/latest/en/localchecks.html), that just does a ping from a raspberry to a server or vice versa.
Or maybe even easier and with a lot more information: Take a look at the MTR (Matt's Traceroute) plugin for the Checkmk agent.

Comment: I used your advice and scripted some python to ping the services and put in the folder of the agents plugin-directory.
working fine :)